# Converting a string that represents a list into an actual list in Jython?

Tags: type-conversion, apache-nifi, jython

I have a string in Jython that represents a list of JSON arrays:

```
[{"datetime": 1570216445000, "type": "test"},{"datetime": 1570216455000, "type": "test2"}]
```

If I try to iterate over this though, it just iterates over each character. How can I make it iterate over the actual list so I can get each JSON array out?

Background info - This script is being run in Apache NiFi, below is the code that the string originates from:

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
...    
def process(self, inputStream):
        text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse a `JSON` similar to how you do it in `Python`.

*Sample Code:*

```python
import json

# Sample JSON text
text =  '[{"datetime": 1570216445000, "type": "test"},{"datetime": 1570216455000, "type": "test2"}]'

# Parse the JSON text
obj = json.loads(text)

# 'obj' is a dictionary
print obj[0]['type']
print obj[1]['type']
```

*Output:*

```
> jython json_string_to_object.py
test
test2
```